# Home security system for android, with automatic friend/foe detection

Tags: android, automation, security, webcam

I am looking for an app that can turn an old smartphone into a home security alarm / baby-monitor / motion sensor.

It should:

- **detect motion**.
  Probably by camera or microphone.
- silently **trigger** some **notification**.
  Preferably by email, sms or call.
- automatically **disarm itself**, when certain other smartphones are nearby.
  No alarm should be raised when a person with a "friendly" smartphone enters. For example by delaying any alarm for a minute and checking the local router's wifi network for the presence of those whitelisted devices. Another option would that the "friendly" phone runs another app that disarms the alarm.
- automatically **rearm itself**, when all such friendly smartphones leave the area.
  No manual interaction should be required to re-enable the alarm.

It should **not**:

- require uploading photos or sound to some sort of **proprietary cloud service**. Does not matter whether that cloud service claims that all data is encrypted.

Purchase price is not a concern, but a non-subscription based app would be greatly preferred. Absence of ads and non-suspicious app permissions would be great bonuses.

Comment: Not having used any of those I cannot vouch for a product; but while waiting for answers, be welcome to check my list on [Re-using your old Android device as webcam / surveillance cam](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_webcams#group_729). [WardenCam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.warden.cam) looks promising if that "cloud storage" part (using your Dropbox account) is optional, which I couldn't see in the desc.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very interesting list. Unfortunately WardenCam seems to fail the **automatic disarm / rearm** requirements. The other apps I checked fail as well, as far as could tell from their manuals (So far I checked AtHome camera, ICamSpy Pro, Alfred, 
IP Webcam Pro, 
Video Monitor - Surveillance,
MobileWebCam, Ocular IP Camera, DroidCamX). If they offer this functionality, it is incredibly well hidden.

Comment: I was just adding a few more candidates while you were browsing the list, so you might wish to check what's new. Thanks for listing ruled-out candidates, which helps potential answerers! As I wrote, I'm not using any of them, so this is as far as I can help. Good luck with your hunt – and hopefully some good answers!